# Quiero listar desde sqlserver una tabla estoy utilizando asp.net 3.1 todo lo estoy utilizando local adjunto el error y la conexión

Tags: json, .net, connection

**Error** 
    [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Aquí esta mi controlador**

> estoy llamando a estos campos de la tabla alumno, pero me aparece que es problema de conexión pero he estado verificando y no contiene ningún error y la conexión se supone que esta bien por que puedo correr las tablas me gustaría que me puedan ayudar a resolver este problema muchas gracias de antemano.

```
 [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<AlumnoViewModel>> Listar()
    {
        var alumno = await _context.Alumnos.ToListAsync();

        return alumno.Select(c => new AlumnoViewModel
        {
            idalumno = c.idalumno,
            nombre = c.nombre,
            apellido = c.apellido,
            callenumero = c.callenumero,
            colonia = c.colonia,
            ciudad = c.ciudad,
            estado = c.estado,
            lada = c.lada,
            telefono = c.telefono,
            pais = c.pais,
            codigopostal = c.codigopostal,
            religion = c.religion,
            correo = c.correo,
            sexo = c.sexo,
            lugarnacimiento = c.lugarnacimiento,
            nacionalidad = c.nacionalidad,
            fechanacimiento = c.fechanacimiento,
            estadocivil = c.estadocivil,
            curp = c.curp,
            tiposangre = c.tiposangre,
            alergias = c.alergias,
            especificarenfermedad = c.especificarenfermedad,
            condicion = c.condicion,
            bautizado = c.bautizado
        });

    }
```

**estoy haciendo mi conexion desde appsettings.json**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"Conexion": "Server=.\\DESKTOP-KB0A8AM\\SERVERSQL;Database:dbsistema;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

**esto es desde services la injection**

```
 services.AddControllers();
        services.AddDbContext<DbContextSistema>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Conexion")));
```

Comment: le pusiste : (dos puntos) en el nombre de la base de datos, siempre llevaron signo =

Comment: Muchas gracias ya lo corregí ahora me comenta que la cadena de conexión no es valida.

Comment: SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

Comment: El sql esta en tu computadora?

Comment: si lo tengo en mi computadora

Comment: Cuando entres al sqlmanagement, fijate la cadena de conexion que te da el login, copiala y pegala tal cual donde dice Server=

Comment: Hey amigo muchas gracias ya me funciono correctamente. era exactamente la cadena de conexión.

Comment: "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Conexion": "Server=DESKTOP-KB0A8AM\\SERVERSQL;Database=dbsistema;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

Comment: te voy a colocar la respuesta, para que quede completa la pregunta con respuesta para otra persona, marcala como correcta

Comment: estoy de acuerdo

Comment: Para que sea mas facil de buscar tu pregunta, cambia el titulo, coloca el error y no coloques imagenes, sino solo codigo y texto sobre los problemas.

Comment: de acuerdo lo tomare en cuenta para mi próxima publicación te agradezco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en la cadena de conexion y la asignacion de la base de datos, corrigiendo el nombre de la cadena al servicio y reemplazando el `:` por `=`

```
 ConnectionStrings": { "Conexion": "Server=DESKTOP-KB0A8AM\\SERVERSQL;Database=dbsistema;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```